# Calling C++ code from Kivy 1.8.0

Tags: python, c++, kivy

I have some numeric code in C++ that I want to call from Python (2.7) and Kivy (1.8,0). The C++ code is in twocomp.dll and I have written an interface module utilizing pycxx and compiled and linked this interface into pycLink.pyd. I can call this link and the dll successfully from a library module scoppylib.py:

```html
import pycLink
import math
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...
```

I have called this Python library successfully from Python programs run from a command line and from inside ipython notebook.

However, when I call the same library from a kivy program, I get the following error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\users\Mailen\SCoPPY\kivy\scop.py", line 9 in module
>
> import scoppylib
>
> File "C:\users\Mailen\SCoPPY\kivy\scooppylib.py", line 7, in module
>
> import pycLink
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

I concluded that the interface pycLink.pyd was not found because of the environment change for kivy, so tried changing PYTHONPATH and tried placing pycLink.pyd in various related directories, but nothing changes the resulting error.

Any suggestions would be welcomed!